# Eloquent take 25 random out of the 400 first rows Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I need to make an eloquent request with top 400 rows, and select 25 random.

Right now the query looks like this. I get the latest 400 rows

```
$result = Model::where('status', '=', 0)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->limit(400)
    ->get();
```

I know that I can do something like this, but then it will take all rows with status 0 but I want 25 out of the top 400.

```
$result = Model::where('status', '=', 0)
    -inRandomOrder()
    ->limit(25)
    ->get();
```

Comment: You can see http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-how-to-get-random-rows/

Comment: $result = Model::where('status', '=', 0)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->take(400)
    ->get()
    ->random(25);

Comment: can you solve it?

Comment: @JewelFarazi the solution is above

Comment: @Evard Akerberg Thanks a lot.